# Zend Framework 2 Radio Button null value default

Tags: forms, zend-framework2, zend-form

I am using Zend Framework 2, Doctrine Module and SQLServer to build a number of products.

I have a question in relation to Zend\Form\Radio.

I have the following defined in a form:

```
 // boolean $disabled_access
$this->add(array(
      'name' => 'disabled_access',
      'type'  => 'radio',
      'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Disabled Access',
            'value_options' => array('1'=>"Yes", '0' => 'No'),
            'allow_empty' => true,
            'nullable' => true,
       ),
      'attributes' => array('value' => null),
));
```

It is bound to a `$building entity`.

If the value of 'disabled_access'  is set to `true` in the DB, the radio button renders correctly.  Similarly if it's is set to `false`.

However, if the column has a NULL value, the radio button defaults to 'No'.  How do I set it up to show all three potential results?

Comment: Have this same issue, did you ever fix?

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough -

`$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'disabled_access',
    'type'  => 'radio',
    'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Disabled Access',
            'value_options' => array('1'=>'Yes', '0' => 'No'),
        ),
    )
);`

If value in database is - 
1 -> 'Yes' radio button will be selected, 
0 -> 'No' radio button will be selected,  
NULL -> none of them will be selected.

Its working for me.

I hope it helps.